# How to suppress `bicgstab` command output in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

This should be a trivial problem to solve....

all I want is to suppress the output of `bicgstab` in `MATLAB`.  For some reason, even when I use the semicolon at the end, it still prints out some information?!?!

Try this example from the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bicgstab.html#f79-999131), and you'll see that it still prints even though I try to suppress the output:

```
A = gallery('wilk',21);
b = sum(A,2);
tol = 1e-12;  
maxit = 15; 
M1 = diag([10:-1:1 1 1:10]);

x = bicgstab(A,b,tol,maxit,M1);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to request the 2nd output argument `flag` to prevent the information being printed (this is actually mentioned in the doc page you link to - it's not that obvious though - just below the table describing the different flag values)

```
[x, flag] = bicgstab(A, b, tol, maxit, M1);
```